# Proper way to handle user accounts with CloudKit

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm creating an iOS app that uses CloudKit and I want my users to log in to the application. Ideally they will just need a username and password. If the password is forgotten they'll need a way to reset it so I'll have to store their email as well.

My question is, What is the best practice for user account information, i.e. username, email, and password?

Is it as simple as storing the username publicly, then the email and password privately on the CloudKit user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing about working with CloudKit on iOS is that authentication is built in. You don't have to worry about usernames and passwords.

When a user connects to your iCloud container via your app, they will only have access to what is stored in their own **private** database. They can also see what you give them access to in the **public** database.

If you can elaborate a bit more of what you are try to do, I can try and give some more guidance. But in short, you don't need to worry about authentication.